# how to get wordpress post with by category with images

Tags: sql, wordpress, module, opencart

I have installed wordpress and opencart in same database. Trying to get wordpress posts table inside opencart module. got the mysql query to fetch all information except image. I dont why images are different from the post in loop of result. Kindly guide, following is the code.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tablename";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
echo "Post ID: " . $row["ID"] . " / ";
echo "Post Title: " . $row["post_title"] . " / ";
echo "Post Title: " . $row["post_date"] . " / ";
echo '<img src="' . $row['guid'] . '" class="img-responsive">';
echo '</div>';
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: You want to display the image in wordpress or in Opencart Module

Comment: opencart have a section of blog posts... in opencart module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your query in phpMyAdmin and check if result you got is the same as you want (you get those pictures that you want).

Then I advise you to set the checkpoint inside the loop and look at the data. Debugging is a very powerful thing in finding errors, it's time to start using [it](https://xdebug.org/download.php)

Comment: it worked perfectly to run a query. I am using My Sql Front application and it worked for me. Thanks infated.

Comment: $sql = 'select * from wp_posts where post_type = "attachment" AND post_mime_type = "image/jpeg" order by post_date ASC limit 3';

Comment: an issue appear. i tried to change the pictures of post and its not changing in browser.